# Problem with installing any app via NPM

Tags: macos

**What's going wrong?**

I try to install something and after the install I can launch it. System doesn't see the installed app.

For example:
I tried to install "appium-doctor" and I did it successfully.

```
npm install -g appium-doctor
/Users/oleg/.npm-global/bin/appium-doctor -> /Users/oleg/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/appium-doctor.js
/Users/oleg/.npm-global/lib
└── appium-doctor@1.4.1
```

After that I tried to launch the appium-doctor, and I got the error:

```
iMac-Ponomarenko:~ oleg$ appium-doctor
-bash: appium-doctor: command not found
```

My environment:
 - npm -v prints: 4.1.2 
 - node -v prints: v6.9.5
 - npm config get registry prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/
 - OS: OS X El Capitan

**What problem is the feature intended to solve?**

I want to install appium 1.6.3. And i need "gulp" for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it by providing full path, like /Applications/some_folder/appium-doctor to launch this app. It looks like system is not able to locate the binary 'appium-doctor'.
If it works then you can add that $path in .bash_profile.

Comment: Yes, it works. I can run the binary 'appium-doctor if I pointed a full path'. How can I paste it variable to .bash_profile?

Comment: Happy to hear the feedback from you, you can edit .bash_profile using vi editor in terminal and add your path along with other $PATH specified. Save .bash_profile and close & re-open terminal for changes to get reflect. So that next time on wards the system will look for the binary in the newly specified location(PATH).